Getting Colour of specific corrdinates of render in sdl
I am developing tatris game and in order to check weather a shape can move down or not i ave to know if there is another figure beneth it. To overcome this i will simply check the pixel colour below it. If it is red then a figure is present oterwise not.
Uint32 get_pixel32(SDL_Surface* surface, int x, int y)
{
    //Convert the pixels to 32 bit
    Uint32* pixels = (Uint32*)surface->pixels;

    //Get the requested pixel
    return pixels[(y * surface->w) + x];
}

SDL_Color GetPixel(SDL_Surface* srf, int x, int y)
{
    SDL_Color color;

    SDL_GetRGBA(get_pixel32(srf, x, y), srf->format, &color.r, &color.g, &color.b, &color.a);
    cout << color.r << " ";
    return color;
}

bool checkcollisiony() {
    if (kfigure.getsdlrect()->y == 450) {
        return true;
    }
    SDL_Window* xwindow = SDL_RenderGetWindow(grender);
    SDL_Surface* xsurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(xwindow);
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(xwindow);
    SDL_Color col = GetPixel(xsurface, kfigure.getsdlrect()->x + 23, kfigure.getsdlrect()->y + 23);
    SDL_Color x = { 255, 0, 0, 255 };
    cout << col.r << " " << col.g << " " << col.b << "       " ;
    cout<< x.r << " " << x.g << " " << x.b << endl;
    if (col.r == x.r && col.g == x.g && col.b == x.b) {
        cout << "!"; return true;
    }

    return false;
}

I tried using this that i found online but for some reason xsurface is blank not null or something else just blank. So how can i check the colour of render given that i know the coordinates

My crystal ball suggests that you’re using the rendering API with this window. This is disallowed.
